# How can I set expected data format using qmicli in Debian jessie?

Tags: networking, modem

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

Hardware: CHIP Pro

***libqmi-utils 1.10.2-2*** installed by apt-get from jessie/main does not have the --set-expected-data-format option.

I am using the EM7430 modem which only supports raw-ip.  On my Rasperry Pi running Debian Stretch, I ran

```
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --set-expected-data-format=raw-ip
```

and the system can get the ip from the modem.

Is there any way of setting the expected data format in Jessie?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade to Stretch or backport yourself the package from source.

Comment: Stretch is a newer version than Jessie.  Jessie has no set-expected-data-format option.  CHIP Pro does not have a Stretch version yet.